# Ionic v1 - Keyboard hides input and creates white bars

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-v1

I hope somebody could help me.
Im running Ionic v1 and Cordova and get a problem. The Keyboard hides my input like on the Screen, and create white bars I tried already these things:

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
```

Also got these Preferences in my config.xml:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true"/>
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateHidden|adjustResize"/>
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false"/>
<preference name="KeyboardResize" value="false" />
<preference name="KeyboardResizeMode" value="native" />
```

[Picture Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6J2K.png)

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from detail provided but make sure your page adheres to the requirements set out in  https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/page/keyboard/ which states:

"On both Android and iOS, Ionic will attempt to prevent the keyboard from obscuring inputs and focusable elements when it appears by scrolling them into view. In order for this to work, any focusable elements must be within a Scroll View or a directive such as Content that has a Scroll View."